# CSRF-token error when added OAuth2 to spring-boot

Tags: spring, angular, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

I've added OAuth2 to my spring-boot application and I'm so far only using google as login. The login part is working correctly but not when I send POST requests I get the following error

```
{
    "timestamp": 1504901957320,
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.",
    "path": "/compute"
}
```

Now I know that I can disable CSRF in spring but thats not best practice. Is spring-boot automatically going to set the CSRF-token or do I have to add something to make it work. Right now I don't know if the problem is when making requests from my angular code that I'm not adding the token

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

this.http.post("/compute", JSON.stringify(source), { headers }).subscribe((response: Response) => {
  if (response.ok) {
    this.mainpage.terminalComponent.logToTerminal(new Date(), response.text());
  }
});
```

Or that I'm not creating the token and setting it from the backend?

Comment: `headers` is not having the `CSRF` token appended to it

Comment: Okej! I just started out with angular so everything is new to me about it. How do I get the token and append it to `headers`? Thanks for the fast answer btw! @Aravind

Answer (score 1):

According to this official [Spring Security and Angular JS tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/).
Angular has a built-in support for CSRF.

> Angular has [built in support for CSRF](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) (which it calls "XSRF") based on cookies.

You can use a custom filter on the spring boot side that send a cookie named `XSRF-TOKEN` back to Angular.

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .httpBasic().and()
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/").permitAll().anyRequest()
        .authenticated().and()
      .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
  }
}
```

For details read the section of the tutorial entitled "CSRF Protection".

Comment: Spring has good documentation for csrf: check [spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/web-app-security.html#csrf)


For angular guide, check angular [doc](https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection)

Hope it helps...